# Is RadioButton with cross instead of bullet possible? - iText 7.1.0 for Java

Tags: itext7

Does anybody know, if it's possible to have a cross (checkbox like) instead of the usual bullet? Did'nt find anything. Thanks a lot! Dirk

[image: Radio Buttons]
To produce this result, I adopted an iText sample

```
package jumpstart;

import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfButtonFormField;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

public class Problem8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("problem8.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdf);
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("src/main/resources/fonts/arialuni.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
        String[] languages = { "Dutch", "English", "French" };
        Rectangle rect;
        Paragraph para;
        PdfButtonFormField radioGroup = PdfFormField.createRadioGroup(pdf, "Language", "");
        pdf.addNewPage();
        for (int i = 1; i <= languages.length; i++) {
            rect = new Rectangle(40, 800 - i * 30, 20, 20);
            para = new Paragraph(languages[i - 1]);
            para.setFont(font);
            para.setFontSize(18);
            PdfFormField.createRadioButton(pdf, rect, radioGroup, languages[i - 1]);
            doc.showTextAligned(para, 70, 800 - i * 30, TextAlignment.LEFT);
        }
        form.addField(radioGroup);
        doc.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("problem8.pdf"));
    }
}
```

Comment: [here you find the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931569/pdf-checkbox-check-one-and-uncheck-another-without-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not possible to change the bullet for a Radio Button completely.**
The solution of Samuel Huylebroeck is working only when interacting with the Radio Button Group:
Then it looks like this after clicking on "Dutch":

[image: clicking on "Dutch"]

But after leaving the Radio Button Group, for example by clicking on another part of the page it looks like this:

[image: leaving Radio Group]

This is the standard appearance of a Radio Button which cannot be altered. That's a pity and it would be very interesting to know why that is so.
*It's confusing that print preview is showing the cross again:*

[image: Print Preview]

Comment: This is an issue with the pdf viewer. Turn off "Highlight existing fields"

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly possible. And one of the FAQ apparently.

https://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/3095

> If you want to replace the appearance, then you have to replace the stream that draws the rectangle and the cross. In IText 7 we added some popular appearances, so you can easily use them while creating elements like:

```
createCheckBox(PdfDocument doc, Rectangle rect, String name, String value, int checkType)
```

> Where checkType can be: TYPE_CHECK, TYPE_CIRCLE, TYPE_CROSS, TYPE_DIAMOND, TYPE_SQUARE, TYPE_STAR. Or you can also change the appearance of existing element using:

```
setCheckType(int checkType).
```

Comment: I read the FAQ. But in my sample there is no checkBox but only a group of radioButtons which have no checkType. Then it's a new document and the code doesn't operate on an existing document. I'm new in iText development and find it hard to get the right information. Can you please give some lines of code which change the bullet into a cross for the RADIOBUTTON. Or is there another FAQ which does the job. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since the example linked by Joris doesn't immediatly apply to radiobuttons (looks like their on-appearance is hard-coded to be a circle by default), I wrote a simple example that shows you how to override that appearance after creating the button-object bu before adding the entire radio group to the form fields:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, java.io.IOException{
    float width = 20;
    float height = 20;
    List<PdfFormField> radiobuttons = new ArrayList<>();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document doc = new Document(pdf);
    //PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("src/main/resources/fonts/arialuni.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
    String[] languages = { "Dutch", "English", "French" };
    Rectangle rect;
    Paragraph para;
    PdfButtonFormField radioGroup = PdfFormField.createRadioGroup(pdf, "Language", "");
    pdf.addNewPage();
    for (int i = 1; i <= languages.length; i++) {
        rect = new Rectangle(40, 800 - i * 30, width, height);
        para = new Paragraph(languages[i - 1]);
        //para.setFont(font);
        para.setFontSize(18);
        PdfFormField radioButton = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(pdf, rect, radioGroup, languages[i - 1]);
        createAndSetCircleGraphicForOn(radioButton,pdf,width,height, languages[i-1]);
        radiobuttons.add(radioButton);
        doc.showTextAligned(para, 70, 800 - i * 30, TextAlignment.LEFT);
    }
    form.addField(radioGroup);
    doc.close();
}

private static void createAndSetCircleGraphicForOn(PdfFormField radiobutton, PdfDocument pdfDoc, float width, float height, String value){
    PdfStream streamOn = (PdfStream) new PdfStream().makeIndirect(pdfDoc);
    PdfCanvas canvasOn = new PdfCanvas(streamOn, new PdfResources(), pdfDoc);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    PdfFormXObject xObjectOn = new PdfFormXObject(rect);

    drawRadioFieldOnWithCross(canvasOn, ColorConstants.BLACK,1f, width, height, true);

    PdfStream streamOff = (PdfStream) new PdfStream().makeIndirect(pdfDoc);

    PdfWidgetAnnotation widget = radiobutton.getWidgets().get(0);

    xObjectOn.getPdfObject().getOutputStream().writeBytes(streamOn.getBytes());
    widget.setNormalAppearance(new PdfDictionary());
    widget.getNormalAppearanceObject().put(new PdfName(value), xObjectOn.getPdfObject());
}

private static void drawRadioFieldOnWithCross(PdfCanvas canvas,Color strokeColor, float strokeWidth, float width, float height, boolean on) {
    canvas.saveState();
    if (on) {
        canvas.
                setStrokeColor(strokeColor)
                .setLineWidth(strokeWidth)
                //bottom left to top right
                .moveTo(0,0)
                .lineTo(width,height)
                .stroke()
                //Top left to bottom right
                .moveTo(0,height)
                .lineTo(width,0)
                .stroke();
    }
    canvas.restoreState();
}
```

It works by replacing the appearance stream for the value-state with a `PdfStream`containing the drawing instructions for a cross instead of a circle.

Comment: Didn't know that something like this was possible! I tried it out and it works for one of the bullets, the one when clicking on the button. When leaving the button there is a second, liitle bit larger bullet. I try to replace it by myself using you great solution an post it here. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Didn't find out how to solve the problem. "An appearance dictionary specifying how the annotation shall be presented visually on the page during its interactions with the user" means, when you leave the radioGroup (clicking on an empty part of the page) there is no interaction any more and a standard bullet is shown. Maybe it's not possible to change this one because it's drawn by the pdf reader itself.

Comment: Hmmm, it's more likely that I didn't replace enough of the appearance streams, I'll have a look at the output again.